# Can you index on a field that isn't in your table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've got two tables, appointment and patient. In this case, I only care about the patient table insofar as it joins to the appointment table. If the patient doesn't have an appointment in a given time period, I want their row to go to the bottom of the stack, and I'd like the patients with the most recent appointments on top.

If there was a column on the patient table for the last_appointment, I'd cluster on that, but there isn't.

here's an example:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#appointment') is not null begin drop table #appointment end
if object_id('tempdb..#patient') is not null begin drop table #patient end
    
    create table #appointment (appt_id int, pat_id int, appt_datetime datetime2)
    insert into #appointment (appt_id, pat_id, appt_datetime)
    values (1, 55, '2021-05-05'),
    (2, 68, '2021-06-06'),
    (3, 74, '2021-07-08'),
    (4, 22, '2019-08-10'),
    (5, 14, '2029-01-12')

    create table #patient (pat_id int, first_name varchar(255))
    insert into #patient (pat_id, first_name)
    values (55, 'Ed'),
    (68, 'Edd'),
    (74, 'Eddy'),
    (22, 'Pinky'),
    (14, 'Mr. Brain')

    select * from #appointment a
    inner join #patient p on a.patient_id = p.pat_id
    where appt_datetime between '2021-01-01' and getdate()

    create clustered index inx_clstr_appt on #appointment (appt_datetime desc)
    create index inx_appt1 on #apptointment (appt_datetime, patient_id)

    create clustered index inx_clstr_patient on #patient (...)
```

The problem is i've got 9 million patients and only a few thousand appointments.

**Question:** How would you order your patient table by their last appointment date without including that column in the table?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the temp tables are just for demo purposes

I think you can achieve your goal by creating an indexed view and then adding a non-clustered index on top of the indexed view.

```
create table appointment (appt_id int, pat_id int, appt_datetime datetime2 constraint pk_appointment primary key (appt_id))
insert into appointment (appt_id, pat_id, appt_datetime)
values (1, 55, '2021-05-05'),
(2, 68, '2021-06-06'),
(3, 74, '2021-07-08'),
(4, 22, '2019-08-10'),
(5, 14, '2029-01-12')

create table patient (pat_id int, first_name varchar(255) constraint pk_patient primary key (pat_id))
insert into patient (pat_id, first_name)
values (55, 'Ed'),
(68, 'Edd'),
(74, 'Eddy'),
(22, 'Pinky'),
(14, 'Mr. Brain')

go
create view ixv_patappt     with schemabinding as 
select a.appt_id,a.pat_id, p.first_name, a.appt_datetime from dbo.appointment a
inner join dbo.patient p on a.pat_id = p.pat_id


create unique clustered index cix_ixv_patappt on ixv_patappt (appt_datetime, pat_id)
```